# Using MediaRouter for route the audio to BT headphones

Tags: java, android

I want to route the audio to a bluetooth headset, or similar outputs if connected. i'm using MediaRouter for this purpose as i understand that what intend to do.
Yet i cannot make it work , as it's not discovering my bluetooth headphones, although its paired.

I'll post the code i'm using for the activity.

And i want to ask, for this purpose i have to use bluetooth framework ? as I want to route the audio only, not to deal with connecting or pairing bluetooth devices.

````
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat;
import androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteActionProvider;
import androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteControllerDialog;
import androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteControllerDialogFragment;
import androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteDialogFactory;
import androidx.mediarouter.media.MediaControlIntent;
import androidx.mediarouter.media.MediaRouteSelector;
import androidx.mediarouter.media.MediaRouter;

public class MediaRouterPlaybackActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MediaRouter mMediaRouter;

    // Active Presentation, set to null if no secondary screen is enabled
    private SamplePresentation mPresentation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.media_route);
        mTextStatus = findViewById(R.id.textStatus);

        Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        Log.d("tag", "on create");


        // Enable clicks on the 'change color' button
        mButton = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showNextColor();
            }
        });

        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(getMediaRouter)
        // Get the MediaRouter service
        mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(this);
        // END_INCLUDE(getMediaRouter)
    }

    /**
     * Implementing a {@link android.media.MediaRouter.Callback} to update the displayed
     * {@link android.app.Presentation} when a route is selected, unselected or the
     * presentation display has changed. The provided stub implementation
     * {@link android.media.MediaRouter.SimpleCallback} is extended and only
     * {@link android.media.MediaRouter.SimpleCallback#onRouteSelected(android.media.MediaRouter, int, android.media.MediaRouter.RouteInfo)}
     * ,
     * {@link android.media.MediaRouter.SimpleCallback#onRouteUnselected(android.media.MediaRouter, int, android.media.MediaRouter.RouteInfo)}
     * and
     * {@link android.media.MediaRouter.SimpleCallback#onRoutePresentationDisplayChanged(android.media.MediaRouter, android.media.MediaRouter.RouteInfo)}
     * are overridden to update the displayed {@link android.app.Presentation} in
     * {@link #updatePresentation()}. These callbacks enable or disable the
     * second screen presentation based on the routing provided by the
     * {@link android.media.MediaRouter} for {@link android.media.MediaRouter#ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO}
     * streams. @
     */
    private final MediaRouter.Callback mMediaRouterCallback =
            new MediaRouter.Callback() {

                // BEGIN_INCLUDE(SimpleCallback)

                /**
                 * A new route has been selected as active. Disable the current
                 * route and enable the new one.
                 */
                @Override
                public void onRouteSelected(@NonNull MediaRouter router, @NonNull MediaRouter.RouteInfo route, int reason) {
                    Log.d("Media route", "onRouteUnselected: route=" + route);
                    updatePresentation();
                }

                /**
                 * The route has been unselected.
                 */
                @Override
                public void onRouteUnselected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info, int reason) {
                    Log.d("Media route", "onRouteUnselected: route=" + info);
                    updatePresentation();
                }

                /**
                 * The route's presentation display has changed. This callback
                 * is called when the presentation has been activated, removed
                 * or its properties have changed.
                 */
                @Override
                public void onRoutePresentationDisplayChanged(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route) {
                    updatePresentation();
                }
                // END_INCLUDE(SimpleCallback)
            };

    /**
     * Updates the displayed presentation to enable a secondary screen if it has
     * been selected in the {@link android.media.MediaRouter} for the
     * {@link android.media.MediaRouter#ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO} type. If no screen has been
     * selected by the {@link android.media.MediaRouter}, the current screen is disabled.
     * Otherwise a new {@link SamplePresentation} is initialized and shown on
     * the secondary screen.
     */
    private void updatePresentation() {

        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(updatePresentationInit)
        // Get the selected route for live video
        MediaRouter.RouteInfo selectedRoute = mMediaRouter.getSelectedRoute();

        // Get its Display if a valid route has been selected
        Display selectedDisplay = selectedRoute.getPresentationDisplay();
        // END_INCLUDE(updatePresentationInit)

        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(updatePresentationDismiss)
        /*
         * Dismiss the current presentation if the display has changed or no new
         * route has been selected
         */
        if (mPresentation != null && mPresentation.getDisplay() != selectedDisplay) {
            mPresentation.dismiss();
            mPresentation = null;
            mButton.setEnabled(false);
            mTextStatus.setText("not connected");
        }
        // END_INCLUDE(updatePresentationDismiss)

        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(updatePresentationNew)
        /*
         * Show a new presentation if the previous one has been dismissed and a
         * route has been selected.
         */
        if (mPresentation == null && selectedDisplay != null) {

            // Initialise a new Presentation for the Display
            mPresentation = new SamplePresentation(this, selectedDisplay);
            mPresentation.setOnDismissListener(mOnDismissListener);

            // Try to show the presentation, this might fail if the display has
            // gone away in the mean time
            try {
                mPresentation.show();
                mTextStatus.setText("test");
                mButton.setEnabled(true);
                showNextColor();
            } catch (WindowManager.InvalidDisplayException ex) {
                // Couldn't show presentation - display was already removed
                mPresentation = null;
            }
        }
        // END_INCLUDE(updatePresentationNew)

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(addCallback)
        // Register a callback for all events related to live video devices
        mMediaRouter.addCallback(
                new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
                        .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_REMOTE_PLAYBACK)
                        .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_AUDIO)
                        .build(),
                mMediaRouterCallback, MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY
        );
        // END_INCLUDE(addCallback)

        // Show the 'Not connected' status message
        mButton.setEnabled(false);
        mTextStatus.setText("not connected");



        // Update the displays based on the currently active routes
        updatePresentation();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(onPause)
        // Stop listening for changes to media routes.
        mMediaRouter.removeCallback(mMediaRouterCallback);
        // END_INCLUDE(onPause)
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(onStop)
        // Dismiss the presentation when the activity is not visible.
        if (mPresentation != null) {
            mPresentation.dismiss();
            mPresentation = null;
        }
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(onStop)
    }

    /**
     * Inflates the ActionBar or options menu. The menu file defines an item for
     * the {@link android.app.MediaRouteActionProvider}, which is registered here for all
     * live video devices using {@link android.media.MediaRouter#ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO}.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {




        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);


        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(MediaRouteActionProvider)
        // Configure the media router action provider
        MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_media_route);


        MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider =
                (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);
        mediaRouteActionProvider.setAlwaysVisible((true));
        mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(
                new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
                        .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_REMOTE_PLAYBACK)
                        .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_AUDIO)
                        .build());

        mediaRouteActionProvider.setDialogFactory(new MediaRouteDialogFactory() {
            @Override
            public MediaRouteControllerDialogFragment onCreateControllerDialogFragment() {
                return new MediaRouteControllerDialogFragment() {
                    @Override
                    public MediaRouteControllerDialog onCreateControllerDialog(
                            Context context, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        MediaRouteControllerDialog mControllerDialog = new MediaRouteControllerDialog(MediaRouterPlaybackActivity.this);
                        return mControllerDialog;
                    }
                };
            }
        });
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE(MediaRouteActionProvider)

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Listens for dismissal of the {@link SamplePresentation} and removes its
     * reference.
     */
    private final DialogInterface.OnDismissListener mOnDismissListener =
            new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    if (dialog == mPresentation) {
                        mPresentation = null;
                    }
                }
            };

    // Views used to display status information on the primary screen
    private TextView mTextStatus;
    private Button mButton;


    /**
     * Displays the next color on the secondary screen if it is activate.
     */
    private void showNextColor() {

    }

}```

I working with this example I found in android docs.
Do you might know how to solve it ?

Im not trying to use google cast only to route to bluetooth speakers or headphones.
````

Comment: Hi Eliran, thanks for creating this question and the details.   I'm curious: were you able to find a solution for this?    I have the same situation where connected Bluetooth devices are not showing up even though they're already connected and can receive audio.   Seems like most sample documentation is aimed at casting video not just audio and / or it might seem like only Google Cast devices show up by default.